# Comparing selected cell value to a cell range values inside parentheses

Tags: excel

I fairly new in excel so don't know much about it or VBA.
I have this dataset shown below, In which first column has some values in it.
I wanted a conditional formatting or VBA formatting(don't know if this exists also!)
to color the data from the 3rd to 5th column based on the selected cell in the first column.

For eg. if I select dbo.project in the 1st column, all the cells having the dbo.project string
in it should be colored/highlighted.

Given Below is the image of my dataset.
[image: Given DataSet]

Comment: Please share a data sample in [markdown table format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) rather than an image of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will activate whenever a single cell in column 1 is selected, and will color all cells containing the selection's text in columns C:E to `vbGreen` color.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Target.Column = 1 Or Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub
With ThisWorksheet
    Dim ColorColumns As Range, Cell As Range, strMatch As String
    Set ColorColumns = Intersect(.Range("C:E"), .UsedRange)
    strMatch = "*" & Target.Text & "*"
    For Each Cell in ColorColumns
        If Cell.Text Like strMatch Then Cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: As Far I understand this code, I think you matching the string in both the cells,
But the Values I wanted to compare in the 3rd to 5th columns are inside parentheses.
I searched some on it I think we have to use Regex for it.

Comment: Have you tried the code? Adding the stars into `strMatch` means that it will work on any cells in `ColorColumns` that contain the text, anywhere in the cell. Google "vba Like operator" for details.